# PHP echo JS for filling form - no new line in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have HTML form which is filled by JS function made by FOR loop in PHP (data is from MySQL base where record name is the same like form name's in HTML)

It looks like this:

```
<?php 
echo<<<END
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
END;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $ile_filtr-1; $i++) 
{
$val=array_values($dane)[$i];
$key=array_keys($dane)[$i];
echo <<<END

$('[name=$key').val('$val'); 

END;
}
echo<<<END
});
</script>
END;
 ?>
```

But when $val contain new line I get:

**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"**

All data from database is sanitized before by:

htmlspecialchars($s,ENT_QUOTES)
and

mysql_real_escape_string

I can bypass error adding:

```
$val= str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), " ", $val)
```

But after that, ther is no new lines in filled textarea.
How to do it properly?

Regards